# Using Asterisk ARI to determine if agent in queue pause or not

Tags: asterisk, asterisk-ari

Is it possible to use ARI to determine if a queue member is paused or not? I can't seem to find any documentation stating that its possible. The only way I can see anything related to a pause is by manually dialing *46 and watching the WebSocket events stream the DeviceStateChange.

Answer (score 1):

Correct way is look for queue_log events. If you put queue_log into mysql it become trivial task.

You also can do queue_status

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-manager-api-action-queuestatus

Comment: I have the queue_log populating into MySQL now, however I don't see anything related to an agent being paused in the queue. Is this something that has to be calculated by looking up the queue agent wrap up time and then comparing the latest `COMPLETECALLER` event?

Comment: From queue_log documentation "PAUSE Written when a queue member is paused.". I am unsure if that triggered when do autopause on no answer. You have check that.